# global memory access for individual threads

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, raytracing

I am writing a simplistic raytracer. The idea is that for every pixel there is a thread that traverses a certain structure (geometry) that resides in global memory.

I invoke my kernel like so:

`trace<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(width, height, frameBuffer, scene)`

Where `scene` is a structure that was previously allocated with `cudaMalloc`. Every thread has to start traversing this structure starting from the same node, and chances are that many concurrent threads will attempt to read the same nodes many times. Does that mean that when such reads take place, it cripples the degree of parallelism?

Given that geometry is large, I would assume that replicating it is not an option. I mean the whole processing still happens fairly fast, but I was wondering whether it is something that has to be dealt with, or simply left flung to the breeze.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you got the wrong idea when you say concurrent reads may or may not cripple the degree of parallelism. Because that is what it means to be parallel. Each thread is reading concurrently. Instead you should be thinking if it affects the performance due to more memory accesses when each thread basically wants the same thing i.e. the same node.

Well according to the article [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/), Memory accesses can be coalesced if data locality is present and within warps only.

Which means if threads within a warp are trying to access memory locations near each other they can be coalesced. In your case each thread is trying to access the "same" node until it meets an endpoint where they branch.

This means the memory accesses will be coalesced within the warp till the threads branch off.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient access to global memory from each thread depends on both your device architecture and your code. Arrays allocated on global memory are aligned to 256-byte memory segments by the CUDA driver. The device can access global memory via 32-, 64-, or 128-byte transactions that are aligned to their size. The device coalesces global memory loads and stores issued by threads of a warp into as few transactions as possible to minimize DRAM bandwidth. A misaligned data access for devices with a compute capability of less than 2.0 affects the effective bandwidth of accessing data. This is not a serious issue when working with a device that has a compute capability of > 2.0. That being said, pretty much regardless of your device generation, when accessing global memory with large strides, the effective bandwidth becomes poor ([Reference](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/)). I would assume that for random access the the same behavior is likely.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are not changing the structure while reading, which I assume you do (if it's a scene you probably render each frame?) then yes, it cripples performance and may cause undefined behaviour. This is called a race condition. You can use atomic operations to overcome this type of problem. Using atomic operations guarantees that the race conditions don't happen.
 You can try, stuffing the 'scene' to the shared memory if you can fit it.
 You can also try using streams to increase concurrency which also brings some sort of synchronization to the kernels that are run in the same stream.

Comment: The question is specifically asking about reads. There are no serialization penalties or race conditions from multiple simultaneous reads from the same location (that is precisely what caches are for) and no such thing as atomic reads in CUDA. I don't understand the point of your answer at all in the context of the question